# How is the data of a numpy.array stored?

Tags: python, numpy

This is my simple test code:

```
data = np.arange(12, dtype='int32').reshape(2,2,3);
```

so the data is:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5]],

   [[ 6,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 11]]], dtype=int32)
```

but why does `data.data[:48]` look like this:

'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00'

I mean why are '9','10' stored as '\t\x00\x00\x00' and '\n\x00\x00\x00'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\t` is the tab character, of [ASCII](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) value 9. `\n` is the LF character, of ASCII value 10. `\x00` is a NUL character, of ascii value 0. Thus,

'\t\x00\x00\x00' represents a sequence of bytes [9, 0, 0, 0], which is a little-endian representation of a long integer 9.

'\n\x00\x00\x00' represents a sequence of bytes [10, 0, 0, 0], which is a little-endian representation of a long integer 10.